# Criterion to assign individuals to clusters in bayesian mixed model with distribution of probabilities

Tags: mixed-model, clustering, hierarchical-bayesian, stan, model-based-clustering

I have a dataset with a set of individuals indexed by $i = \{ 1, ..., N \}$, and I make a number of measuremenets under two conditions for each individual to measure the effect $\beta$ of my manipulation. I am fitting a mixture model to the dataset, where I have two populations of individuals, a population 1 of individuals with their effects given by $\beta_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta, \sigma)$ and a population 2 of individuals with $\beta_i = 0$, where $\beta_i$ is the effect of the manipulation on individual $i$.

In the mixture model that I am fitting, I thus estimate, among others, the parameters $\beta$, $\sigma$, $\beta_i$, and the mixing probability $p$ that an arbitrary individual belongs to population 1. I am fitting this model in STAN, so it's a fully bayesian model where I get posterior distributions of each parameter.

With the mixing probability $p$ and the likelihood of the data for an individual $i$ conditional on this individual belonging on each of the populations, I can get the probability $p_i$ that the individual $i$ belongs to population 1. In this sampling framework, I thus end up with a posterior distribution on $p_i$. That is, for each individual I don't have a probability that it belongs to population 1, but a distribution of probabilities of the individual belonging to population 1. In some experiments, I may expect the distributions of $p_i$ to be somewhat broad.

One of the goals of my analysis is to assign individuals to the two different populations. But I am not sure what is the best way of doing this. If I just had a probability $p_i$ for each individual, I suppose that it would be sensible to just set a threshold, e.g. 0.5, and assign an individual to population 1 when $p_i > 0.5$. But given that I have a distribution of $p_i$ for each individual, I'm not sure how to proceed (of course a simple way would just be to set a threshold on the expected value of $p_i$).

Is this a known type of problem? What are some possible ways to use these posterior distributions of $p_i$ to assign individual $i$ to a population?

(I posted my model code in the Stan forum [here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/finding-clusters-within-random-effects-individuals/31940/6), in case that helps)